# My Project is throwing 11 errors when I'm trying to create .ipa file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I'm in this wired situation, I'm able to build and run my project without a single warning, error or leak. However, when I'm trying to create archive file it gives me 11 errors. as below.
[image: errors]

Can any1 plz suggest me why this happening? Moreover, when I select project target and go to info in my localizations, in Resources, 0 Files Localized. is there any connection between this and my problem. here is the image.
[image: Target info]

I'm using xcode Version 4.2 and mac os Version 10.6.8.
Please help me with this. I ll really appreciate it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your image round.png. It is saying that it is not a png file. Check if it was actually one or not.

Comment: Thanks mate for your help. I have Solved the issue it was some .png files that was creating some trouble.

Comment: happy to help.. I had the same issue.. :) Always try to track the error report. They use to be quite helpful..